# Can't get paypal sandbox to work https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am following paypal steps "How to Test PayPal Payments Standard Buttons"

Step 3 is log into
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

I am getting a 404 on this page.

Am I looking at old instructions or have this moved or is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine for me. You can try to clear your browser's cookies and cache . You can also try to visit :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your alternative login link allowed me access :)